# Run single cucubmer scenario via cuke4duke and maven

Tags: maven, cucumber

I'm using maven and cuke4duke-maven-pluign to run cucumber features. Is it possible to run a single cucumber scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its sure possible like this:
https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/tree/master/examples/i18n/en
In this example you can use only divide for example.
For another example you want to test a calculator.java simply.
In there thats possible, you can test only add.feature in this test skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

One thing we do in our projects using cuke4duke is to create a property for cuke4duke arguments:

```
<project ...>
  <properties>
     <cukeArgs>--tags ~@wip --tags ~@benchmark --tags ~@html</cukeArgs>
  </properties>


  <build>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>cuke4duke</groupId>
      <artifactId>cuke4duke-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${cuke4duke.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <cucumberArgs>
          ...
          <cucumberArg>${cukeArgs}</cucumberArg>
        </cucumberArgs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </build>
</project>
```

Using that you can do the following:

```
mvn cuke4duke:cucumber -DcukeArgs="-n cooking"
```

to run features that have `cooking` in their name.

Answer (score 0):

Use cucumber.features property on the command line, for example:

```
mvn cuke4duke:cucumber -Dcucumber.features=features/self-registered-login.feature
```